# Getting 'org.hibernate.HibernateException' when calling toString() on Optional in Hibernate

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm encountering an issue with Hibernate where I'm getting a 'org.hibernate.HibernateException' when trying to call toString() on an Optional object. Here's the scenario:

I have a Hibernate entity mapped to a database table, and one of the properties is declared as an Optional in my model. When I try to retrieve an instance of the entity using Hibernate, I receive the exception when attempting to call toString() on the Optional object.this problem accurred when I added a logo to the client but at first  everything was fine

[I am debugging an API that returns opportunities based on their stage. It is also supposed to provide the description associated with each opportunity. However, I am encountering an issue where the description is not being returned correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kndzm.png)

[Here is  the description: "When I test the API using Postman, I receive the following error message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFxZl.png)

**Here is the EtapeEntity **

```
package com.example.crm_amosys_orass.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;
@Entity
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "crm_Opportunite_etape")
public class EtapeEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private  Long idEtape;
    private String name;
        // Constructors, getters, and setters
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "etape", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<OpportuniteEntity> opportunite;

}
```

**Here is the OpportunityEntity **

```
package com.example.crm_amosys_orass.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "crm_opportunities_information")
@Builder
@Component
public class OpportuniteEntity {
//Type
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long idOpportunity;
        private String name;
      //  private String stage;
        private LocalDate closeDate;
        private String Statu;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "idUser")
        private UserEntity user;


        /*@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "idClient")
        private ClientEntity client;*/

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="idEtape", nullable = false)
         private EtapeEntity etape;


    //@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  /******  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="idEtape")
    EtapeEntity etape1;*******/
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "opportunite", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<ProduitOpportuniterEntity> produits;
      /*  @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "opportunity_product",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idOpportunity"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idProduct"))
        private Set<ProduitEntity> products = new HashSet<>();*/

    //*********************************************************************************

   @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idClient")
    private ClientEntity client;

}
```

**Here is the ClientEntity **

```
package com.example.crm_amosys_orass.model;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
@Entity
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "crm_client_information")
public class ClientEntity {
    //Classe Client
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idClient;

    @Column(name = "Entreprise_Principal")
    private String entreprisePrincipal;
    @Column(name = "SiteWeb_Entreprise")
    private String siteWebEntreprise;
    @Column(name = "Nom_Prenom")
    private String nomPrenom;
    @Column(name = "Code_Client")

    private String codeClient;
    @Column(name = "Fax")
    private String fax;

    @Column(name = "Tele_Fix")
    private String teleFixe;

    @Column(name = "E_mail")
    private String email;

    @Column(name ="Linkdin")
    private String linkdin;

    @Column(name ="Register_Commercial")
    private String registerCommercial;

    @Column(name ="Chifre_D'affir")
    private String chifreDaffir;
    @Column(name ="nombre_Employe")
    private String nombreEmploye;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") // Specify the date pattern
    @Column(name = "Date_creat_Client")


    private LocalDate dateCreatClient;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") // Specify the date pattern
    @Column(name = "DateAgrement")

    private LocalDate dateAgrement;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idCountry")
    private CountryEntity country;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
    private List<ContactEntity> contacts;
    //    lllllll
    //    @OneToMany
   //     List<ProduitEntity> produits;
   @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateAchatP;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
    private List<ProduitClientEntity> produits;
   // @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
    private List<OpportuniteEntity> opportunites;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private LogoEntity logo;
}
```

** Here is the EtapeController  THIS API ni Work **

```
 @GetMapping("/crm_etape_etapeOpp/{idEtape}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<OpportunityDTO>> getOpportunite(@PathVariable long idEtape){

        return new ResponseEntity<>(etapeService.getOpportunite(idEtape),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

** Here is the EtapeService **

```
  public List<OpportunityDTO> getOpportunite(long idEtape) {
        Optional<EtapeEntity> etape = etapeRepository.findById(idEtape);
        List<OpportuniteEntity> opportunites = etape.get().getOpportunite();
       // List<OpportuniteEntity> opportunites1 = etape.get().getOpportunite();
        return opportunityMapper.ToOpportuniteDtos(opportunites);
    }
```

[code source](https://github.com/RajaBenBourch/cem_amosys_orass)

Comment: You could try to evaluate `etape.toString()` in the debugger to see if the problem is with your class or not. Probably it is

Comment: Also you could investigate the stackstrace of this exception to see exactly where it's failing. It has to be somewhere in your classes where you have a broken `.toString()` implementation.